# Are there any advantages, bonus points, or effects for not losing people?

Tags: bridge-constructor-portal

I've noticed that sometimes, little people spawn on the backs or fronts of the trucks. They jump or fall off when scraped against a strut, or when the car flips over.

But, I can still finish the level (with full points) with cars without their hangers-on.

Are there any effects to losing or preserving these people? Bonus points, or maybe a secret achievement?